# Send a mail inside botman (laravel 5.7)

Tags: laravel, email, botman

I struggle to send a mail inside a botman reply.

I use mailhog, with botman 2.0 and  laravel 5.7.

I've tested mailhog with simple php code , it work.

Here my env file config :

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=localhost
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

The conversation start here :

```
<?php

namespace App\Conversations\SASI\CreationTicket;

//use Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Incoming\Answer;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Conversations\Conversation;
use App\Conversations\SASI\CreationTicket\EndTicketResume;

class EndTicket extends Conversation
{
    public function askProblem()
    {
        $this->ask('Décrivez succintement votre problème :', function(Answer $answer) {
            $this->bot->userStorage()->save([
                'problem' => $answer->getText(),
            ]);

            $this->askEmail(); //passe à la fonction suivante
        });
    }
    
    public function askEmail()
    {
        $this->ask('Quel est votre email?', function(Answer $answer) {

            $validator = Validator::make(['email' => $answer->getText()], [
                'email' => 'email',
            ]);

            if ($validator->fails()) {
                return $this->repeat('Cette email ne semble pas valide. Entrez un email valide.');
            }

            $this->bot->userStorage()->save([
                'email' => $answer->getText(),
            ]);

            $this->askMobile();
        });
    }

    public function askMobile()
    {
        $this->ask('Quel est votre numéro pro?', function(Answer $answer) {
            $this->bot->userStorage()->save([
                'mobile' => $answer->getText(),
            ]);

            $this->say('Merci');
            
            //renvoi a une autre conversation app\Conversations\SelectServiceConversation.php
            $this->bot->startConversation(new EndTicketResume());
        });
    }
    
    public function run()
    {
        $this->askProblem();
    }
}
```

As you can see the bot say "Merci" (thanks) and go to another conversation. If add my mail code the bot stop before he say "Merci"

So the next conversation :

```
<?php

namespace App\Conversations\SASI\CreationTicket;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Conversations\Conversation;

class EndTicketResume extends Conversation
{
    public function confirmTicket()
    {
        $user = $this->bot->userStorage()->find();

        $message = '------------------------------------------------ <br>';
        $message .= 'Probleme : '.$user->get('problem').'<br>';
        $message .= 'Email : '.$user->get('email').'<br>';
        $message .= 'Tel : '.$user->get('mobile').'<br>';
        $message .= '------------------------------------------------';

        $this->say('Votre demande va être envoyé. <br><br>'.$message);

        $email = $user->get('email');
        

        $data = [
            'first' => 'test',
            'last' => 'TEST'
        ];
          
        // send email with details
        Mail::send('emails.justshoot', $data, function($message) use ($email) {
            $message->subject('Welcome');
            $message->from($email, 'Just Shoot Upload');          
            $message->to('myemail@gmail.com')->cc('test@gmail.com');
        });

    }

    /**
     * Start the conversation.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->confirmTicket();
    }
}
```

If I remove this

```
    Mail::send('emails.justshoot', $data, function($message) use ($email) {
        $message->subject('Welcome');
        $message->from($email, 'Just Shoot Upload');          
        $message->to('myemail@gmail.com')->cc('test@gmail.com');
    });
```

The bot say his last message, all is ok. But if I add this code , as I said previously, the bot won't even go to another conversation.

What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the mail in a seperate function and different controller
you can debug using network tab in the console